# how to determine the broadcast address for IP of class-A when net mask is of class-B

Tags: networking

What is the broadcast address for IP address 94.239.172.157 with net mask 255.255.0.0 ?
this IP address belongs to Class - A 
but it uses default mask of class - B 
how can I finds it's broadcast address ?

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast address is always the highest address in the subnet.

If your IP address is 94.239.172.157 with a netmask of 255.255.0.0, that means that the subnet's network ID is 94.239.0.0 (the lowest address) and its broadcast address is 94.239.255.255 (the highest address).

If your netmask in this case was 255.255.255.0, your broadcast address would be 94.239.172.255.

Also, note that the first octet really doesn't indicate class anymore.  You can [read up on CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

Answer (score 0):

If the info is correct then the Mask for the subnet 255.255.0.0, then its simply 94.239.255.255.  Search for an ip calc and enter the ip and subnet mask to confirm if you want.